# How Cross- Filtering works within Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I possess a dataset, and within it, I've established three tables: "Total Measures," "Customer Info," and "Tenant Info." The "Total Measures" table encompasses all metrics/measures which I have defined in the custom SQL, while the other two tables exclusively display customer and tenant information. My objective is to enable cross-filtering, where selecting a measure from the "Total Measures" table should also affect the related tables.

However, despite verifying the scoping, it appears that the cross-filtering isn't functioning as expected. I'm uncertain about what might be missing or misconfigured in this setup.